# RX 6700 XT CPU Spec and RAM Size for Optimum Mining

Tags: mining

I have 13 slots motherboard and planning to put 6700s on it, upgrade it from rx570s with Celeron processor and 8Gig ram. Do I need to upgrade the CPU and the ram size also? If yes, what is the most optimum CPU and RAM spec for the setup so that it doesn't draw lots of power?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I managed to install 6700 with celeron and 8 gig ram, lspci command recognized it. Case closed.